# Transposing a matrix using python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, inverse

This is my current matrix:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 4],
 [0, 3, 1, 3],
 [0, 2, 3, 2],
 [0, 2, 4, 1],
 [0, 4, 1, 2],
 [0, 3, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 2]]
```

I want to transpose it and get this as output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [2, 2, 4, 3, 2], 
 [3, 4, 1, 2, 2], 
 [2, 1, 2, 2, 2]]
```

I used `inverse = np.swapaxes(ate,0,7)` but I am not sure what will be my `axis2` value be. Here the `axis2` is 7.

Comment: what happens to the first two rows.  Also, I think you meant transpose not inverse.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is np.transpose()

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.swapaxes`, however this swaps "dimensions", so for a matrix that's either `0` or `1` because you have two dimensions:

```
>>> np.swapaxes(arr, 0, 1)   # assuming your matrix is called arr
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2],
       [2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2],
       [4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2]])
```

To get your desired output you'd need to remove the first two columns before the `swapaxes`:

```
>>> np.swapaxes(arr[2:], 0, 1)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [2, 2, 4, 3, 2],
       [3, 4, 1, 2, 2],
       [2, 1, 2, 2, 2]])
```

However generally you should use `np.transpose` or `.T` if you want to transpose the matrix/array:

```
>>> arr[2:].T
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [2, 2, 4, 3, 2],
       [3, 4, 1, 2, 2],
       [2, 1, 2, 2, 2]])
```